How to Resolve SonarQube Maven Plugin Java Version Compatibility Error?
I am encountering an issue when trying to run the SonarQube analysis on my project using the SonarQube Maven plugin. The error message indicates that there is an API incompatibility due to the Java Runtime version. Below is the detailed error message:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:4.0.0.4121:sonar (default-cli) on project XplTrack: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:4.0.0.4121:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:4.0.0.4121:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] realm = plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:4.0.0.4121

[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/4.0.0.4121/sonar-maven-plugin-4.0.0.4121.jar

[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar

[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar

[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar

[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.3.1081/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.3.1081.jar

[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ZAKARIA/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar

[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1

[ERROR] import: Entry[import from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------

[ERROR]

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Additional Context
SonarQube Version: 10.6
Maven Version: 3.8.1
Java Version: 11.0.25 (LTS)
pom.xml Configuration
<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

<version>3.8.1</version>

<configuration>

<source>11</source>

<target>11</target>

<compilerArgs>

<arg>-parameters</arg>

</compilerArgs>

</configuration>

</plugin>

Command Run
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \

-Dsonar.projectKey=test-maven \

-Dsonar.projectName='test-maven' \

-Dsonar.host.url=<sonarqube_url> \

-Dsonar.token=<token>

How can I resolve this error and successfully run the SonarQube analysis?

That code requires at least Java 17 (class file version 61), not Java 11 (class file version 55)

Upgrade to minimum JDK 17 related to the SonarSource also Upgrade your Maven version 3.9.X ...

if I upgrade the java to 17 the project need java 11 for building
because I tried that and got this error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project XplTrack: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x7da9dfa) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x7da9dfa

Newer versions of Java are much stricter about allowing access to internal classes. So you will need to upgrade other parts of the build to versions which work with newer versions of Java. Or use an older version of SonarQube that was compiled for Java 11.

First I would really reconsider to use Lombok... on the other hand you could use a more recent version of Lombok (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/versions) .. also the compiler-plugin is a bit old... (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) So you have to maintain that project and keep up-to-date....

You can't have it both ways. Either upgrade JDK and all dependencies of the project or downgrade Sonar. The first one will be better long term but it is up to you.

@aled which sonarqube version is compatible with our project

Have you tried sonarqube documentation?
